# MongoDB C# driver returns MissingMethodException. Any workaround?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, console-application

I'm writing a fairly simple console app using .NET Core and trying to attach to a Mongo DB. It appears that the current release has been broken because of changes to the DnsClient (i.e. the actual error is: Method not found: 'DnsClient.IDnsQueryResponse DnsClient.LookupClient.Query(System.String, DnsClient.QueryType)'.). Is anyone aware of a work-around for this problem as the Mongo-ites don't seem in any rush to get a fix out for us poor C# junkies?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a ticket created regarding this issue in mongodb issue tracker

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2330

Also, there is a comment inside the ticket with a workarund:

> I found the solution of this problem.  DnsClient 1.1.1 cause this
> error. downgrade to 1.0.7, and try again.
>
> if you see error "Could not load file or assembly 'DnsClient' or one
> of its dependencies. Manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference",make sure to check redirect setting in web.config.
> newVersion section in "dependentAssembly/bindingRedirect" should be
> "1.0.7.0".

Actually, I got this exception as well. Follow the above steps solved my problem.